# How to parse a Hash of Hashes from a CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I have a CSV file that I need to read and extract all rows which have a "created_at" within a certain range.  The CSV itself is about 5000 lines in Excel.

This is how I am pulling the info from the file:

```
CSV.foreach("sample_data.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
  data[row.fields[0]] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
end
```

Here's the last Hash created after using `CSV.foreach`:

```
2760=>{:created_at=>1483189568, :readable_date=>"12/31/2016", :first_name=>"Louise", :last_name=>"Garza", :email=>"lgarza24n@drupal.org", :gender=>"Female", :company=>"Cogilith", :currency=>"EUR", :word=>"orchestration", :drug_brand=>"EPIVIR", :drug_name=>"lamivudine", :drug_company=>"State of Florida DOH Central Pharmacy", :pill_color=>"Maroon", :frequency=>"Yearly", :token=>"_", :keywords=>"in faucibus", :bitcoin_address=>"19jTjXLPQUL1nEmHrpqeqM1FdtDFZmUZ2E"}}
```

When I run `data[2759].first` I get:

```
created_at
1309380645
```

I need to pull every hash where `created_at` is between `range = 1403321503..1406082945`. I tried about twenty different methods using `each` and `collect` on the `data` hash with no success. My last attempt printed out an empty `{}` for each original hash.

I'm trying to test this with no success:

```
data.each do |hash|
  if hash.first.to_s.to_i > 1403321503 && hash.first.to_s.to_i < 1406082945
    puts hash
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to isolate the value of `key:created_at` and then see if it is within the range. I also tried doing `hash.first.to_s.to_i =/==` range.

I am able to get just the `:created_at` value by using `data[1].first.last` but when I try to use that in a method it errors out.

Here is a link to the original CSV: goo.gl/NOjAPo

It is not on my work computer so I can't do a pastebin of it.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's happening from your description. You need to provide a few rows of data, _runnable_ code that's producing the wrong answer, and the corresponding correct answer.  E.g. it's not at all clear whether `data` is a hash or an array. Why don't you just index the hash with symbols, `hash[:created_at]`?

Comment: Hint: `(x..y).include?(z)` is a more concise way of checking if something is inside a given range. What you have here is a lot more verbose and requires a bunch of redundant method calls.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind when doing Ruby is to try and break down your problem into a series of chained but simple operations. For example, `reject` the rows you don't want, or `select` the ones you do, *then* `puts` them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only store rows in the `data` hash that are within the range. IMO that performs betters, because it needs less memory than reading all data into `data` and remove the unwanted entries in a second step.

```
DATE_RANGE = (1403321503..1406082945)

CSV.foreach("sample_data.csv", 
            :headers => true, 
            :header_converters => :symbol, 
            :converters => :all) do |row|
  attrs = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
  data[row.fields[0]] = attrs if DATE_RANGE.cover?(attrs[:created_at])
end
```

It might make sense to check the condition before actually creating the hash by checking `DATE_RANGE.cover?` against the column number (is `created_at` in `row.fields[1]`?).

Comment: Please respect ppl with not-so-wide screens, split long lines in the answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa I thought is was okay, because that line was provided by the OP, didn't cause the problem and is unchanged in my answer. Sorry about that. I updated my answer with an improved line length.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to remind to those who listens only :)

Comment: This looks great. I wasn't sure if I could actually try to parse the CSV directly before putting into a hash(without the use of regex or something).  

I'll check this out when I get back to my computer!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. One typo in your post is .covers? should be .cover?  
Thank you so much!

Comment: @BridgerReifHammond: Yes, you are right. The method is named `cover?` and not `covers?`. I fixed my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
hash.select do |_, v|
  (1403321503..1406082945) === v[:created_at]
end
```

Here we also use [`Range#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) also known as case-equal, or triple-equal, to check if the value is inside the range.

Comment: When I have tried doing something like that before it error'd out. I did get it working with .to_s.to_i though.  

Should I add .to_s.to_i inside the brackets or outside?  

v[:created_at].to_s.to_i  
or  
v[:created_at.to_s.to_i]

Comment: Converting symbol to string and then to integer makes not much sense. It is unclear, why you’d do that, but if you want, convert the whole `v[:created_at]` value.

Comment: When I was trying to use = or == with the range I was getting errors that I was comparing to the type, tried .to_i alone but that didn't work so I did -> string -> integer to make sure it was an integer.